# Classifying labeled tweets using WEKA

Tags: weka, sentiment-analysis

I'm looking into using sentiment analysis and Weka to classify tweets as belonging to one of 3 classes based on a pre-labeled data set.

The data set has 6 attributes in the form:

```
count(num), hate_speech(num), offensive_language(num), neither(num), class(num), tweet(string)
```

where *class* and *tweet* are the interesting attributes. The class attribute is a numerical value (0, 1 or 2) and the tweet is a string containing the raw text of the tweet. Does anyone know how to do this? When using the explorer in Weka there's a lot of configurations that can be made and I don't know where to start. As a first step I would like to use Naive Bayes or SVM to classify the tweets.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, use the StringToWordVector filter to split the tweet text  up into words, and then use the NaiveBayesMultinomial Filter to classify.

Optionally you could also do preprocessing of texts ( all-lowercase , word stemming etc) with Weka's Filters. (maybe do this before loading data into weka - might save you a lot of clicks). Also put the "class" column in the last position of your datafile.